# Breeze not populating entities from navigationProperties

Tags: breeze

I have client-side defined metadata, like so:

```
helper.addTypeToStore(manager.metadataStore, {
  name: 'PriorStudy',
  dataProperties: {
    priorStudyId: { type: breeze.DataType.Int32 },
    priorStudyType: { max: 6 },
    priorStudyPurpose: { max: 12 },
    notes: { max: 250 }
  }
});

helper.addTypeToStore(manager.metadataStore, {
  name: 'Patient',
  dataProperties: {
    patientId: { type: breeze.DataType.Int32 },
    firstName: { max: 25 },
    lastName: { max: 25 },
  },
  navigationProperties: {
    priorStudies: { entityTypeName: 'PriorStudy', fk: ['patientId'], hasMany: true}
  }
})
```

My JSON response from the server is shaped like this:

```
{ FirstName: "Steve",
  LastName: "Holt",
  PatientId: 1,
  PriorStudy: [
    {
      PriorStudyId: 1,
      PriorStudyType: "BLAH",
      PriorStudyPurpose: "Whatever",
      PatientId: 1,
      Notes: "la la la"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm testing the creation of entities like so:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Patient/1').toType('Patient')
console.log(query);
manager.executeQuery(query).then(function (results) {
  console.log(results);
})
.then(function () {
  var ents = breeze.EntityQuery.from('PriorStudy').using(manager).executeLocally();
  console.log(ents);
});
```

The Patient entity is created as expected, but no matter what I attempt the PriorStudy entity is empty. I'm about to resort to writing a JsonResultsAdapter.

I know this sounds a lot like other questions, but I've been banging my head against it for two days and don't know what else to try. Any advice would be tremendously appreciated.

EDIT: Link to non-working code
https://gist.github.com/dlmanning/c09fe225995bc7cb682b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a few things here.

1 - You're redefining your client side metadata incorrectly. The correct definition for your 'PriorStudy' entity type should look like this.

```
    name: 'PriorStudy',
    dataProperties: {
       priorStudyId: { type: breeze.DataType.Int32 },
       patientId: { type: breeze.DataType.Int32 },
       priorStudyType: { max: 6 },
       priorStudyPurpose: { max: 12 },
       notes: { max: 250 }
    },

    navigationProperties: {
      patient: 'Patient',
    }
```

Notice the 'patientId' foreign key as well as the 'patient' scalar navigation property.

Then the definition for your 'Patient' entity type can look as follows.

```
    name: 'Patient',
    dataProperties: {
      patientId: { type: breeze.DataType.Int32 },
      firstName: { max: 25 },
      lastName: { max: 25 },
    },

    navigationProperties: {
      priorStudies: { entityTypeName: 'PriorStudy', hasMany: true }
    }
```

Notice that you don't specify the 'priorStudies fk' property on the 'Patient' entity type.

2 - When you have defined the metadata correctly, then in your query, you can query your Patient with the 'expand' method to also bring the 'PriorStudies' from the database.

`var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Patient/1')
   .toType('Patient')
   .expand('priorStudies');`

EDIT 1:

Adding [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pPT2rgQWQapc1P1ERt2z)

EDIT 2:

In addition to defining (and fixing) the client-side metadata, you also have to write your own custom JsonResultsAdapter. Look for the Edmunds and ESPN samples on the [Breeze Samples](http://breezejs.com/samples) page. The [Breeze mapping json](http://breezejs.com/documentation/mapping-json) tutorial, may also prove to be helpful.

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/dkoswara/c3e82d513943b8ac929a) that I've created to illustrate how to write a custom `jsonResultsAdapter`. Look for the `createJsonResultsAdapter` method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! now getting an error when trying to load the data:

`TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at updateRelatedEntityInCollection (http://localhost:1337/js/lib/breeze.debug.js:14542:40)`

Looking in the debugger it appears that relatedEntity is somehow a raw object (thus lacking a getProperty method) instead of being wrapped as an entity. Any ideas?

Comment: Hard to tell unless I see some code. I added my plunkr link to demonstrate how this should work. Perhaps you can see and compare what you're doing different.

Comment: Sorry to take so long to reply. Had to do other things.

So I notice in your Plunkr example on lines 108-110 you're doing explicitly what I'm trying to make happen implicitly: Creating the PriorStudy entity and adding it to the Patient entity.

To be clear: I'm getting the whole object graph in JSON format from the server and trying to get breeze to parse the whole thing into the Entity store.

Thanks so much for all your help.

Comment: I've added a link to the original post with my non-functioning code. It looks pretty awful, but was just my attempt to teach myself how breeze works.

Comment: I'm sorry. I completely missed that you had no control over the server's json response in your original post. You're correct. In addition to defining (and fixing) the client-side metadata, you also have to write your own custom JsonResultsAdapter. Look for the Edmunds and ESPN samples on http://www.breezejs.com/samples. This link, http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/mapping-json, may also prove to be helpful. In the meantime, I'll work on updating my post to show a more complete answer.

Comment: Okay, thanks! At least it's validating to know I'm not crazy :)